# Why does JBoss prepend the JAR name to my Java package names?

Tags: java, jboss, classloader

**This is in regards to JBoss 5.1.0:**

I'm used to dropping JARs directly under my EAR and having the classes picked up. When the ClassLoader does a diagnostic dump, it lists all the JARs under the ear and then all the Java packages found in said JARs.

I have this archive `jsqlparser-bin.jar` that is erroneously not listed as a JAR despite being under the EAR. However, its packages *are found*, but they are all prepended with the name of the JAR! So instead of listing packages like `net.sf.jsqlparser.schema`, it lists `jsqlparser-bin.jar.net.sf.jsqlparser.schema`.

I also noticed in the dump other *archive-prepended package names* such as `jaxb-impl.jar.com.sun.xml.bind.api`. This lead me to believe if the same package was included in more than one JAR, then JBoss did some creative renaming, hence the prepend. However, if I completely removed `jsqlparser-bin.jar` from the EAR, then no version of the packages were ever dumped. So now I'm clueless. I also scanned the other archives in the EAR for `jsqlparser` but came up empty. `jsqlparser-bin.jar` itself is kosher, since I am able to compile with it (and not compile without it).

So what gives? How do I make the classes in that JAR visible? Why does it not have its own `DelegatingHandler` in the classloader hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I needed to add a `<module>` block in my `META-INF/application.xml` to resolve it correctly.